# Problems with networking after suspend

Tags: networking, suspend

I have some problems on my Asus notebook since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10:

- Networking (wifi and lan) won't work after resume from suspend. I've seen many posts about this but they wouldn't work for me (adding iwlwifi to the list of loaded modules).

I couldn't find anything on that problem, and I don’t know where to look at to solve that. Is there any information I can add?

Comment: 1) Here is the syslog generated when I activate the wifi before a suspend (works) http://pastebin.com/KQq3DqkW ; and here is the syslog generated when I try activating wifi after a suspend (doesn't work) http://pastebin.com/7KrAnUnf .

Comment: Looking at the answers this is a bug.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi-connection

Comment: [Bug #1286552 - No wifi after suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1286552).

Comment: Another workaround is to `sudo service network-manager restart`. I know it's not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 18):

Sounds like bug [#1234469: Network does not come up after resuming from suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1234469).

The workaround is to run:

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

This workaround uses the ***nmcli*** to change the sleep state of the ***nm***.

***nmcli*** is the *Network Manager command-line interface*
***nm*** is the *Network Manager*

Comment: This helped me a bit on 12.04 Xubuntu, after this and manual suspend, the card start blinking again, but finally no success on getting it worked. Only wifi is working, the RJ45 eth0 jammed after resiming from suspend.

Comment: That was fast. Is it permanent?

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, very good question: freddybob, do you know if this is permanent? Seven years later, and I'm dealing with same issue! I would totally love to prevent the network from dying when I lock the machine - I'm bemused that this would ever be thought a good idea, it breaks all the services and jams the GUI, and it seems to have become the default since 20.04, argh!

Comment: @freddybob Is this even valid any more? On 20.04, I get: `Error: argument 'nm' not understood. Try passing --help instead.` - has the option been removed? Struggling to find alternative...

Comment: you could try `nmcli radio wifi on`

Answer (score 3):

That workaround did not work for me. However this worked:

> I have still no solution but I have found a workaround:
>
> Create a new shellscript named `hibernate.sh`. Open it with gedit and
>   paste the following code:
>
> ```
> gnome-screensaver-command -l dbus-send --system --print-reply \
>     --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
>     /org/freedesktop/UPower \
>     org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
> ```
>
> Save it and make it executable. If you want you can create a .desktop
>   file for it. When you run this script it will send your pc into
>   hibernate-mode including the lockscreen. When you wake your pc now
>   networking works. When you use sleep-mode or hibernate-mode the normal
>   way it doesn't.

Thanks to Christopher Paul over here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1212199

Note that you'll need to restart your system once after that (if your network was out due to a suspend when you did the script). Then it works fine.

Also note this script sends your pc to suspend, not to hibernate (the name could be confusing).