# Networking/WiFi disabled and unable to enable after resuming from suspend in 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

After *waking* the system from *suspend* my networking is disabled and will not start again, this started happening after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 90:fb:a6:a8:52:40
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:f0010000-f0010fff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 00:26:82:a3:fa:70
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:f1100000-f1103fff
```

Comment: What is your wireless driver from the terminal: sudo lshw -C network

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with networking after suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend)

Answer (score 0):

This technique sometimes, but not always works. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

A new, empty file will open. Add a single line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="wl"
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. It may take a reboot to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had installed ubuntu 13.10 on a new machine but messed my network setting up.

1. I installed gksu
2. Runned: sudo gksu gedit
   in gedit open your network interfaces file found in etc-network-interfaces
3. Edit the file with:

   -# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system

   -# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

   -# The loopback network interface

   -auto lo

   -iface lo inet loopback

   -# This is a list of hotpluggable network interfaces.

   -# They will be activated automatically by the hotplug subsystem.

   -# auto eth1

   -# iface eth1 inet dhcp

   then just save it.
4. Just to make sure everything is ok 
   a. please check your dhcpd.conf file found in etc-dhcp-dhcpd.conf to make sure

   option domain-name "example.org";

   option domain-name-server ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

   default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;

   do not have # before them.
5. now retart your system and I hope it works just like mine did