# Cannot get wireless network after suspend

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, suspend, broadcom

I've been working on an issue of calculation for months, but I can't get my wireless card to work. It always shows to me : Device not ready.

My laptop is Acer 4750g with Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) and the Ethernet controller is Broadcom Corporation Netlink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe.

I've tried

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

but nothing changed.

After that, I've updated my wireless card diver from 
http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=570x/linux-3.118k.zip

And I got :

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                   drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
Cannot get link status: Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone knows how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([Problems with networking after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/suspend-problems-in-13-10)) or this ([How to restart the networking service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service)), there should be something in all the solutions what can help you.

Comment: No, I've tried bash and restart network-manager already. It does not work for me. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it's solved by removing and immediately reinserting the modules for the wireless.

```
sudo rmmod rt2800usb && sleep 3s && sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

or

```
sudo rmmod ath9k && sleep 3 && sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Notice that this are the commands I use in my laptop and in my desktop. You'll need to find out which modules your wireless uses. I think by your post you're using a Qualcom Atheros like mine, so try the second command first.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I choosed the second command, and nothing seems changed. I've already add in /etc/modprobe.d/ath9.conf to close the wake on lan by echo >

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've tried with Chili555, please check another question posted.

[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Network Icon Mistaken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392532/ubuntu-12-04-lts-network-icon-mistaken)