# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Network Icon Mistaken

Tags: 12.04, networking, icons

After some diagonic processure, I've found that my wireless network has not yet resolved but my wired connection has mistaken the wrong icon.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:6a:8a:3f:70:90  
          inet addr:172.29.2.181  Bcast:172.29.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226a:8aff:fe3f:7090/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1324723 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:260711 (260.7 KB)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:79866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:79866 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10583710 (10.5 MB)  TX bytes:10583710 (10.5 MB)

WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1600000-f160ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:6a:8a:3f:70:90
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=172.29.2.181 latency=0 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f1400000-f140ffff memory:f1410000-f141ffff memory:f1450000-f14507ff
```

WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.

Anyone can help?

According to Chili555, I've tried modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath

```
[339970.692404] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[339970.692409] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[339970.809499] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[339970.809504] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[339970.925151] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[339970.925156] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[340612.711783] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[340612.711789] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[340612.829633] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[340612.829639] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[340612.945773] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[340612.945779] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[340626.001522] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[340626.001527] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[346785.942351] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[346785.942356] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[346786.059931] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[346786.059936] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[346786.176004] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[346786.176009] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[347318.499218] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[347318.499224] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[347335.167438] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[347335.167444] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[347335.284839] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[347335.284845] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[347335.400957] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[347335.400962] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[348371.939924] ath: phy0: Chip reset failed
[348371.939929] ath: phy0: Unable to reset hardware; reset status -22 (freq 2412 MHz)
[349456.895035] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[349465.420567] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[349465.535474] ath: phy1: Couldn't reset chip
[349465.535478] ath: phy1: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -5
[349465.535484] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[349465.535575] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
[349648.631049] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[349658.068003] ath: phy2: Couldn't reset chip
[349658.068008] ath: phy2: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -5
[349658.068014] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[349658.068066] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
[427830.275860] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[427833.430991] ath: phy3: Couldn't reset chip
[427833.431006] ath: phy3: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -5
[427833.431023] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[427833.431280] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
[428873.448746] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[429026.303871] ath: phy4: Couldn't reset chip
[429026.303877] ath: phy4: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -5
[429026.303882] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[429026.303969] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
[429088.070481] ath9k: ath9k: Driver unloaded
[429115.975556] ath: phy5: Couldn't reset chip
[429115.975560] ath: phy5: Unable to initialize hardware; initialization status: -5
[429115.975565] ath9k 0000:03:00.0: Failed to initialize device
[429115.975616] ath9k: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: sudo modprobe ath9k and also: dmesg | grep ath

Comment: OK. I have added in my main question section due to the strict page propreties in comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also add: uname -r. There are several 12.04 LTS versions all using different kernels. My suggested fix depends on your kernel.

Comment: 3.5.0-44-generic, this is my current version linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install a later version of the driver ath9k. With a working wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic
```

Reboot and let us hear your report. If it is not working as expected, let's see:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked after I reboot my computer. Sorry for this lateness of my reply, the calculation work do not admit a reboot. After all worked normal, I have also tried the command demsg | grep ath, and what I got is : (sorry I have to trim this message)  [4.248277] ath :: EEPROM regdomain : 0.65, ...., [150.693146] ath9k : ath9k : Driver unloaded. I am very happy that my wlan card works, but do you think this message is normal?

Comment: I see nothing unusual or abnormal here. I'm glad it's working. Please accept my answer.

Comment: OK. Because it displays that a ath9k : driver unloaded, and it shows something else, so I worried that...Sure, I will accept your answer, you have done a great help to me. Thank you very much, chili555. :)))