# Wireless Adapter Disconnects after Suspend on 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, suspend, disconnect

After suspending and resuming my machine, my wireless networking fails to reconnect. Running `nmcli nm` shows the following:

Before:

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled
```

After:

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

Even running `sudo service network-manager restart` fails to do anything. Only by restarting the machine have I been able to reconnect.

EDIT: More info

Hardware:
The wireless adapter is a `Rosewill RNX-N180UBE`.
It is attached via USB to an `Asus H87I-Plus` motherboard. (This is a custom-built PC)

Running `lsusb` shows the following for the adapter:
`Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information about your hardware (laptop model, wifi card model, etc)

Comment: Iǘe got the same problem with an external usb wifi dongle. With me it helps to unplug the dongle and plug it back in. I have no other current solution to this though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with networking after suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend)