# Dell Latitude e6400 on Ubuntu 14.04 not working after resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, dell

After resume from suspend, my Dell Latitude E6400 is not working and I get a message like saying wifi connection is offline and the system is unavailable. As a result I have to reboot the system.

Is there a way to troubleshoot the issue or apply a fix?

Detail regarding network interface:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:6a:95:bc:3c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-30-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:f1ffe000-f1ffffff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with networking after suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've fixed the issue by installing proprietary NVIDIA driver. Just had to select from

**System Setings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > Use NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)**

So, resume from suspend on my DELL E6400 is working as expected.