# 14.04 Wifi doesn't turn back on after sleep

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, suspend

Related questions have been asked quite often, but the solutions mentioned in those questions don't seem to solve my problem.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04) quesion seems to be on the right track and I use it as a general guide. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend) question is also related.

So, when my WiFi is on and connected and I run `nmcli nm` I get:

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled
```

If I then close the lid (sleep) and open it again (wake up) and run the command again, I get:

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    disabled        disabled   enabled         enabled
```

So the `WIFI-HARDWARE` and `WIFI` statusses changed from `enabled` to `disabled`.

Running `man nmcli` gives options I can use with `nmcli nm` and shows that I can switch WIFI on using `nmcli nm wifi on`, however if I run this it doesn't change the status of `WIFI-HARDWARE` or `WIFI`.

I think I can use a bash script and nmcli to fix this, but am not quite sure how. The original question says the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
        resume|thaw)
        nmcli nm sleep false
                ;;
esac
```

should be placed in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, this does however not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on 16.10 where my Wifi would not reconnect after resuming. I tried restarting NetworkManager in a on-resume script, but it didn't work.

The solution that worked for me disabling and/or uninstalling ModemManager. Once that was gone, it started connecting again.